# Is 'reason being' grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the usage of 'reason being' ungrammatical?

I heard so many times people use this. I don't know is this correct usage or not.

Answer (score 1):

***Reason being*** [**that**] [blah blah] is a common colloquial alternative to ***because***. In many contexts, strict grammar would require it to be preceded by ***the***, but people often omit that definite article.

It's a stylised version of what might more "properly" be expressed as *The reason **is** [that] [blah blah]*, but in practice people don't often use that version. Reason being if they cared about clarity and brevity they'd probably use *[This / Whatever I just said is] **because*** anyway.

I could justify my choice of phrasing in the preceding sentence by claiming it's *illustrative* of the usage under consideration, but *in general*, it's just ***quirkiness for quirkiness's sake***. It's probably not something learners should use outside of relaxed conversational contexts - regardless of whether it's made "grammatical" by including the article, it'll always come across as being at least *slightly* quirky.